# How to resize a DataGridView in Panel

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# programming.

I made a side menu in my main_form with some icons and I wanted to open new forms at the same page, so I placed a panel in main_form. I used this code to do it:

```
        panel_main.Controls.Clear();
        customer new_form = new customer();
        new_form.TopLevel = false;
        panel_main.Controls.Add(new_form);
        new_form.Show();</code>
```

I placed a DataGridView in the form which I wanted to show it in, but whenever I maximize main_form the DataGridView don't resize with main_form.

Comment: You can set Dock and Anchor properties, provided you understand them.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using the IDE designer to do the work that you're doing, so that the initialization code is written for you. That way when you drag out the panel to your form and adjust the size, you can drop a DataGridView in the panel and set the Dock property of the DataGridView to Fill and the DataGridView will always fill the panel.